# How can I create a class with constructor and functions in R like java or c++?

Tags: r, function, class, constructor, rscript

I want to write R script class like java or c++ programming language. But, I didn't find any example. Here is the main structure of a class in java or c++:

```
Myclass{

  param1
  param2
  ...

  Constructor(...){
    .
    . 
    .
  }

  function1(...){
    .
    . 
    .
  }

  function2(...){
    .
    . 
    .
  }

  .
  . 
  .
}
```

Is it possible to create a class like the above? Can anyone show me an example?

Comment: Honestly R's object-oriented programming options are too involved for a simple answer to make sense in a forum like this. There are several "OOP" schemes in R, and they all work differently. I would read [Part III of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html), then come back to Stack Overflow and ask a specific question if you're still having trouble after that.

Comment: See `?ReferenceClasses`.

Comment: Adding to the other comments. Reference classes or R6 classes are the way to go.